# The Column space of A

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is vector $\mathrm c = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\3 \end{pmatrix}$ in the column space of $\mathrm A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\ 5 & 6\end{pmatrix}$?

My solution:

For this vector to be in the column space of A then there must be Ax = c. So to begin this problem I would multiply vector A by $\begin{pmatrix} c_1 \\ c_2 \\ c_3 \end{pmatrix} $ and let that equal to vector c and then solve for the variables $c_1$ $c_2$ $c_3$. Just wondering if this logic is correct before I begin the problem

Answer (score 1):

The logic is almost correct, as there are only  $2$ coefficients to find ($A$ is a $3\times 2$ matrix). Note you solve more that what is asked.

Here it obvious $c$ is $\frac12$ the second column.

When things are not so obvious, the lazy way would consider the augmented matrix $Ac$ and determine by row reduction whether  it as the same rank as $A$. If it is the case, it means $c$ in  the subspace spanned by the column vectors of $A$.

If you proceed to a *full* row reduction, you have an automatic way to find the coefficients you find by your strategy.

*Some details:*

\begin{align*}
Ac=&\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\3&4&2 \\5&6&3\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&-2&-1\\0&-4&-2\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&2&1\\0&-4&-2\end{bmatrix}
\rightsquigarrow\begin{bmatrix}1&2&1\\0&2&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\\[1ex]
\rightsquigarrow &\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&2&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\rightsquigarrow \begin{bmatrix}1&0&\color{red}0\\0&1&\color{red}{\frac12}\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Comment: okay so do I let matrix A = c1 c2 c3 or 0 0 0?

Comment: A = c1 c2 c3  (or 0 0 0) is impossible, since $A$ has  $2$ columns. I don't really understand what you want to do.

Comment: I am not sure I am a little confused

Comment: I've updated my answer. Is it clearer?

Comment: okay that makes sense, so from there on how i go about answering if c is in the colum space of a?

Comment: The obvious solution I mention in my  updated answer.

Comment: we found what Ac is equal to

Comment: and we know the 2nd column is 1/2

Answer (score 0):

There is a shortcut to finding a basus fir the image of a linear map in matrix form. Row reduce, and then pick out the linearily independent columns.

When you do this, the problem reduces to finding if there exists some $a,b$ for which
$$
a(1,3,5)+b(2,4,6)=(1,2,3)
$$
Or solving another system to see if the given vector is in the span of the image vectors

Comment: okay so I need to reduce A into row echelon form?

Comment: Yes, but only to find the columns with leading 1's, these are a basis for the image

Comment: okay once I reduce my vector into echelon form with leading ones how do I go about solving it?